# How to select a value from a dropdown using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a `<a href="">` in which I have written some code for a popup window as shown below :

```
<a href="#" class="editpermission" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editPermission" data-permission-name="{{ $permission->name }}" data-group-name="{{ $permission->pgname }}" data-permission-id="{{ $permission->id }}">Edit</a>
```

On clicking the above link, a popup window opens as shown below :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editPermission" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Permission</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="formbox">
                    <form action="" method="post" id="permission-edit-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="permissionName">Permission Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="permission-name" id="permission-name" class="form-control" maxlength="50" value="">
                            <span id="permission-error" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="permissionGroup">Permission Group</label>
                            <select name="permission-group" id="permission-group" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                @foreach ($permissionsGroups as $permissionsGroup)
                                    <option value="{{ $permissionsGroup->id }}" {{ old('permission_group') == $permissionsGroup->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $permissionsGroup->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            <span id="permission-error-group" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="permission-id" id="permission-id" value=""/>
                        <div class="btngroup">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have some script code for cliking on the `<a>` tag.

```
$('.editpermission').click(function() {
        $('#permission-id').val($(this).data('permissionId'));
        $('#permission-edit-form #permission-name').val($(this).data('permissionName'));
        $('#permission-edit-form #permission-group').val($(this).data('groupName'));
    });
```

In the above script code, I am trying to select the value of `permission-group` into the select dropdown in the popup window which has a group name in `foreach` where all the data in the dropdown is obtained from the table. I want to select the value `$(this).data('groupName')` in the popup window dropdown in the popup window. Can anyone help me out in this ?

Comment: `.data('permissionName')` but your attribute is `data-permission-name` - same for `data-group-name` / `.data("groupName")`

Comment: I have changed it.bit its not working.

Comment: Changed it to `.data("permission-name")`?  Then can you provided the *rendered* html?